# How to 'mark' a node in a Clojure data structure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have

- a Clojure data structure, let's call it `dom`, a tree of vectors and
  maps of indefinite depth;
- a particular node in it, let's call it the `focus` node, referred to as
  a path into the tree: a sequence of keys such as you could present to
  `get-in`.

I will be deciding on the focussed node in one function and I want to somehow represent that choice  of focussed node in a way that can be passed to another function in a way that does not violate immutability and is not in conflict with Clojure's persistent data structures.

When I traverse the tree, I want to treat the `focus` node differently: for example, if I was printing the tree, I might want to print the `focus` node in **bold**.

If I were using C or Java, I could save a pointer/reference to the `focus` node, which I could compare with the current node as I traversed the tree. I don't think that's the right way to do it in Clojure: it feels hacky, and I'm sure there's some way to do it that takes advantage of Clojure's persistent data structures.

The solution has to work in Clojure and ClojureScript.

The options I can think of are:

1. Store a reference and check against that.
2. Attach a marker to the node in question.
3. Simultaneously recurse into the tree and along the path to the marked node.

   - Option (1) is unattractive, as I've explained.
   - Option (2) seems best, and painless given persistent data structures.
   - Option (3) is similar to option (2), except that it combines the
     marking and traversing steps.

I'm sure this is a common problem. Is there a standard solution to it?

Comment: I guess you could use metadata to implement 2 but I am not aware of a general solution

Comment: Thank you. I could use metadata, but probably wouldn't. The question is a bit broader than the implementation.

Comment: It never hurts to re-read that, but I don't think I'm asking a question that is primarily opinion based. It is entirely possible (and I have no way of knowing) that there is a standard idiomatic pattern for doing this. If the answer is 'no', that's a valid answer.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for functional lenses. clojure.zip maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you reconsider @MerceloMorales's suggestion: to use metadata. Your node object is to have an accidental attribute that doesn't affect its normal functions. That is what metadata is designed for. And it works in ClojureScript. The only reason I can think of for *not* using metadata is that the node value is not a Clojure object, but is, for example, a number.

In [*The Clojure Cookbook, 2.22. Keeping Multiple Values for a Key*](https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/02_composite-data/2-22_multiple-values/2-22_multiple-values.asciidoc), Luke Vanderhart uses metadata to solve a similar problem: marking entries that need to be interpreted as collections rather than single values.

Another approach might be to use a zipper to traverse/modify the node tree. Zippers are implemented in terms of - you've guessed it - metadata.

I share your misgivings about metadata: it feels queasy to attach just any old stuff to your data - like infecting it with a parasite. However, it's just as immutable a part of the object as any other.

---

The suggestion to use zippers is naive: The [standard clojure zippers](http://richhickey.github.io/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html) are designed for a hierarchy of sequential containers, not associative ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I wasn't clear about what I said about metadata: I have no problem using it, but it doesn't matter if I use metadata or some other method for storing the 'mark'. I was just asking a more general question about the approach.

Comment: I think I've struggled to communicate my question, and maybe shouldn't have given an example. I just want to indicate a particular node in a tree based on a path so that another function can identify the node. I'll see if I can edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Joe Very well put :). Examples help, though.

Answer (score 1):

See Brandon Bloom's [Dendrology talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgvJqWiyMRY) for some great overview on questions like this.

I believe the ease of "marking" or otherwise updating tree structured data underlies his strong recommendation to always represent nodes as nested maps rather than vectors (or a mixture of vectors and maps). A mark based on a path described by a vector of keys is then as simple as:

```
 (update-in tree-data path assoc :is-focussed true)
```

Your original data structure is unchanged and the new one returned by update-in shares everything structurally with the original except the updated node which is now easily tested for the `:is-focussed` property upon traversal.